# How to escape a jquery string

Tags: jquery

I use jquery to parse string

```
message="<div messageid=999 value=something>hello</div>";
$(message).attr('messageid');
```

This works great... except when message contains some chars like **:!**

```
message="!hello world!";
$(message).attr('messageid');
```

what would be the solution to solve that problem ?

Comment: In the second example the string does not contain html tags and also there is no mesageid attribute but you are trying to acces it, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a string as the first parameter to the jQuery function ($), the function tries to determine if it is a selector or an HTML string.

When you use an exclamation point or colon, and there are no HTML tags in the string, jQuery will assume it's a selector, because "!" and ":" are part of selector syntax.

That's why a call to `$('!hello world!')` throws an error.

You can force it to treat it as an HTML string by using [**$.parseHTML**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/):

```
$($.parseHTML(message)).attr('messageid')
```

Note that there's *no* problem using "!" and ":" if there are tags in the string:

```
message="<div messageid=999 value=something>:No problems here!</div>"
$(message).attr('messageid')
```

---

My answer is based on the assumption that you're trying to avoid a run-time error.  Querying an attribute on `$('hello world')` or `$($.parseHTML('!hello world!'))` would obviously return `undefined`.

Comment: message="!hello world!"; $($.parseHTML(message)).attr('messageid');

Gives me the SAME error

Comment: It doesn't give an error in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/v7meufvq/  What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Wrapping it in `console.log` makes it appear in the console, but the value returned is still `undefined` because any given string doesn't have a `messageid` attribute.

Comment: Correct, it's `undefined`, but that's different from throwing an error, which happens when you don't use `$.parseHTML`.

Comment: I retract my statement. Forgetting to add jQuery to my testing environment led me to an incorrect answer and a misconception of the asker's problem.

Comment: Not a problem!  I think many people would assume the "error" is that it returns `undefined` rather than this is a run-time error.